# Javascript Deep Copy Squel Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Nodejs to try to make a deep copy of an object created by a query building library called Squel. The question itself, however, is how to make an exact copy of the `filteredQuery` variable.

The object is created by: `filteredQuery = squel.select()`

The console.log of the object is available below. It looks like a Javascript Object with a "_class42" string in front of it.

How can I make a deep copy of the `filteredQuery` variable?

Note: I have tried `filteredQuery2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filteredQuery));` However, that returns the object itself but not the "_class42" string in front of it

npm lodash, clone and deepcopy modules make a pointer not a copy of this object as well.. weird..

`console.log(filteredQuery)`:

```
_class42 {
  options:
   { autoQuoteTableNames: false,
     autoQuoteFieldNames: false,
     autoQuoteAliasNames: false,
     useAsForTableAliasNames: false,
     nameQuoteCharacter: '`',
     tableAliasQuoteCharacter: '`',
     fieldAliasQuoteCharacter: '"',
     valueHandlers: [],
     parameterCharacter: '?',
     numberedParameters: false,
     numberedParametersPrefix: '@',
     numberedParametersStartAt: 1,
     replaceSingleQuotes: true,
     singleQuoteReplacement: '\'\'',
     separator: ' ',
     stringFormatter: null,
     rawNesting: false },
  blocks:
   [ _class6 { options: [Object], _str: 'SELECT' },
     _class18 { options: [Object] },
     _class37 {
       options: [Object],
       _parent: [_class34],
       top: [Function: _limit] },
     _class13 { options: [Object], _fields: [] },
     _class11 { options: [Object], _tables: [] },
     _class27 { options: [Object], _joins: [] },
     _class24 { options: [Object], _conditions: [Array] },
     _class19 { options: [Object], _groups: [] },
     _class26 { options: [Object], _orders: [] },
     _class38 { options: [Object], _parent: [_class34] },
     _class36 {
       options: [Object],
       _parent: [_class34],
       limit: [Function: _limit] },
     _class28 { options: [Object], _unions: [] } ],
  distinct: [Function],
  top: [Function],
  fields: [Function],
  field: [Function],
  from: [Function],
  join: [Function],
  left_join: [Function],
  right_join: [Function],
  outer_join: [Function],
  left_outer_join: [Function],
  full_join: [Function],
  cross_join: [Function],
  where: [Function],
  group: [Function],
  order: [Function],
  offset: [Function],
  limit: [Function],
  union: [Function],
  union_all: [Function] }
```

Comment: Suggestions welcome as well so I can try them out..

Comment: @nurbol how is this a duplicate of that question? Please explain. For a start this is javascript, your post is c#..

Comment: I don't see any Javascript questions on SO answering how to clone this type of object.. the problem enlies with the `_class42` string in front of the Javascript object.

Comment: `_class42` is the class name of the object. it means this object is an instance of `_class42` and was probably constructed by calling `new _class42()`. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filteredQuery))` only clones json data, not class information.

Comment: I think you're right.. How would I create a deep copy of the class instance though. I keep getting pointers when I try `Object.assign()`

Comment: `console.log` is implementation-defined, it can and frequently does show whatever it feels like including things you don't necessarily have programmatic access to.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar a while back and I stumbled onto this...

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        var out = [], i = 0, len = obj.length;
        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            out[i] = arguments.callee(obj[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        var out = {}, i;
        for ( i in obj ) {
            out[i] = arguments.callee(obj[i]);
        }
            return out;
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I have to admit, I cannot remember the source so cannot give credit.  But, a quick search yields plenty of results.  For example, this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab).  Which also gives some really good examples and explanations around copying objects.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this clone function

```
const clone = obj =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
      ? new Date(obj.getTime())
      : (typeof obj === 'object') && obj
        ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => ({ ...o, [prop]: clone(obj[prop]) }), {})
        : obj;
```

If it is an array, return an array with a clone of each object, if it is a date return a date with the same time, if it is an object, return a clone with each property cloned or just return the item if it is a reference or function. Falls over if you have arrow function methods but work for most objects.

Comment: Nice one but also creates a pointer to the original in this case

Answer (score 0):

A workaround on this is to use the sql-template-strings library instead of squel.

Then, a simple lodash deep clone does the job.

```
const SQL = require('sql-template-strings') //instead of squel
const _ = require('lodash');
...
var query = SQL`SELECT author FROM books WHERE name = ${book} AND author = ${author}`
var query_clone = _.cloneDeep(query)
```